# How to make button disabled if all checkbox are unchecked in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

There are 3 check boxes and I have to make one check box mandatory . Like if all checkbox are un checked then button should be disabled . Please help me for that . How I can do .

```
<View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', paddingLeft: 15 }}>
  <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <CheckBox color="#00678f" 
      checked={this.state.notification.isContactByPost}
      onPress={() => this.handleChange('isContactByPost')} 
    />
 </View>
 <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
   <Text style={{ fontSize: 14 }}>Post</Text>
 </View>
 <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
   <CheckBox color="#00678f"
     checked={this.state.notification.isContactByEmail}
     onPress={() => this.handleChange('isContactByEmail')} 
   />
 </View>
 <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
   <Text style={{ fontSize: 14 }}>Email</Text>
 </View>
 <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
   <CheckBox color="#00678f"
     checked={this.state.notification.isContactBySms}
     onPress={() => this.handleChange('isContactBySms')}
   />
 </View>
 <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
   <Text style={{ fontSize: 14 }}>SMS</Text>
 </View>
</View>  
<View style={{ marginTop: 50 }}>
 <PrimaryBtn 
   label={'submit'}
   disabled={false}
   onPress={() => this.OnButtonClick(this.state.notification)} 
 />
 </View>
 </View>
```

Thanks

Comment: To make one mandatory change `disabled={false}` to `disabled={!this.state.notification.isContactByPost}` for example to make isContactByPost mandatory

Comment: Thanks for your help, but there are 3 boxes if all are unchecked then it should disable else on 2 unchecked it should enable

Comment: If @Deckerz solution didn't work, could you please show us your `handleChange` method?

Comment: @IanStebanVasco im not the question owner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you can do it

```
<PrimaryBtn label={'submit'} disabled={!this.state.notification.isContactByPost && 
    !this.state.notification.isContactByEmail && 
    !this.state.notification.isContactBySms}  onPress={() => 
    this.OnButtonClick(this.state.notification)} />
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks a lot  I was doing || or condition that's why.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```js
render(){
  const {isContactByPost,isContactByEmail,isContactBySms } = this.state.notification; 
  return (
    <PrimaryBtn 
      label={'submit'} 
      disabled={!(isContactByPost || isContactByEmail || isContactBySms)}
      onPress={() => this.OnButtonClick(this.state.notification)} 
    />
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this (to make it more simple i removed redundant parts) =>

```
const {isContactByPost, isContactByEmail, isContactBySms} = this.state.notification
const isButtonDisabled = !(isContactByPost || isContactByEmail || isContactBySms)

<PrimaryBtn disabled={isButtonDisabled} /> // don't forget your others props :)
```

Comment: Thanks you everyone